# multiline conf file to parse log file to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have this log file: http://dpaste.com/3FE2VNY

I only want to extract certain pieces of information such as date time, and number of events posted. My attempt of putting this into elasticsearch results in hanging of logstash. Not sure what I did wrong as I am new to this.

What I attempted to do was to simply grab all the content in the log file and pass it into elasticsearch. I understand that `grok` must be used to grab specific parts but I am not at that level just quite yet.

My goal is to extract:

```
start: Mon Apr 27 13:35:25 2015
finish: Mon Apr 27 13:35:36 2015
number of events posted: 10
```

Log file:

```
test_web_events.py: START: Mon Apr 27 13:35:25 2015
# TESTCASE TestWebPost ==================================================
# START TEST METHOD #################################: test_10_post_valid_json
[2015-04-27T13:35:25.657887] HTTP DELETE http://pppdc9prd3net:8080/rastplatz/v1/sink/db?k0=bradford4
{}
HTTP response: 200
0
POSTING event_id b29b6c7c-48cd-4cd9-b3c4-aa0a7edc1f35 to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 13678af1-3e3a-4a6e-a61c-404eb94b9768 to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 47b70306-2e7c-4cb2-9e75-5755d8d101d4 to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 6599cdb2-0630-470d-879d-1130cf70c605 to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id d088ce29-fa0d-4f45-b628-045dba1fd045 to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 07d14813-b561-442c-9b86-dc40d1fcc721 to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id b6aea24a-5424-4a0f-aac6-8cbaecc410db to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 016386bd-eac5-4f1c-8afc-a66326d37ddb to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 6610485d-71af-4dfa-9268-54be5408a793 to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 92786434-02f7-4248-a77b-bdd9d33b57be to businessevent
Content-Type: text/plain
Posted 10 events
# END TEST METHOD ###################################: test_10_post_valid_json
test_web_events.py: FINISH: Mon Apr 27 13:35:36 2015
```

conf file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/bli1/logstash-1.5.0/tmp/bradfordli2_post.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^."
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { protocol => http host => "127.0.0.1:9200"}
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: would you like to extract the 3 pieces of information as separate log events? Then you don't need to work with multiline at all...

Comment: @markus I would like to extract the 3 pieces of information and then send it to elastic search as one event

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
multiline {
    pattern => "START:"
    negate => "true"
    what => "previous"
}
```

This instructs the multiline filter/codec to put all lines not containing START: in the previous logevent.

You can then use grok patterns to extract your 3 pieces of information. Take care you have to instruct grok to look in a multiline messages by using the multiline swith at the beginning of your grok pattern like so:

```
grok {
    match => ["message", "(?m)Posted %{NONNEGINT:nrEvents} events"]
}
```

A word of warning if you are working with multithreaded inputs / several parallel worker threads. There are currently bugs in logstash multiline handling that can lead to lines from various events mixing each other up when being processed in parallel. I'm nor sure if that is relevant for you but take a look at this:

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1754

Another word of info. I don't really understand what's the difference between mutline filter and codec and when use one or the other. I use the filter in my project and it works fine however.